# Cannot add to cart configurable product after migration - MAGENTO

Tags: php, ajax, magento, addition, product

From 2 days I cannot figure it out. I tried everything and i was surfing in internet by hours... My problem:

I migrated Magento from 1one1 to ovh and after migration my products which are configurable (for example color to choose) dont want to add them to cart, products without configuration works fine. Adding is supporting by Ajax, and console turns:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

http://name.com/ajax/index/add/uenc/aHR0cDovL3NsZjI0LmNvLnVrL2xlYXRoZXIt…My1zZWF0ZXItc29mYS5odG1sP19fX1NJRD1V/product/69/form_key/LxYZLhN081LKalZb/

Andy ideas? :/ 
Maybe there are any important changes which I have to apply after migration?

Thanks for reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

500 is server error. check server logs, what exactly happened. It may be even server ram problem, or to short execution php script time.

Comment: Mhm.. This is not server error.. After set off Ajax and turn on Developer Mode the error is  Fatal error: Call to a member function setProductName() on a non-object in /home/slfcoukkvp/www/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Model/Observer.php on line 387

Comment: did you reindex all data in index management and clear cache and session? Try edit configurable product and save it

Comment: Damn.. After Reindex all data the options and "add to cart" in configurable products gone. What do u think?

Comment: Is it possible that during migration database there were errors? I ask for reindex end edit/save to check database problems (many informations ara save in two types of tables). Problem is in this line : $stockItem = $option->getProduct()->getStockItem(); check for configurable product its related products.